# PHP: Getting error when when trying to replace DATA in a text file

Tags: php

Text file name: Fruits.txt

This file contains 4 lines:

```
Apple
red
sweet
1kg
```

If I add data about APPLES then the above lines should get replaced with the new data but if I add data about any other fruit then it should be appended in the text file.

**Errors Getting:** Notice: Undefined offset: -1 and Notice: Undefined offset: 1

**My code:**

```
$dir = "./fruits.txt";

$end = 0;
$name = $_GET['fruits'];
$handle = fopen($dir,"r");
while(!feof($handle)){
$line = fgets($handle);
$end++;
}
fclose($handle);

$line = file($dir);

for($i=0;$i < ($end -1); ++$i){

$fruit_name = trim($line[$i]);
if($name == $fruit_name){

$contents = file_get_contents($dir);
$contents = str_replace($line[$i + 3],'',$contents);
file_put_contents($dir,$contents);

$contents = file_get_contents($dir);
$contents = str_replace($line[$i + 2],'',$contents);
file_put_contents($dir,$contents);

$contents = file_get_contents($dir);
$contents = str_replace($line[$i + 1],'',$contents);
file_put_contents($dir,$contents);

$contents = file_get_contents($dir);
$contents = str_replace($line[$i],'',$contents);
file_put_contents($dir,$contents);
}
}
$new_data = "$name\r\n$color\r\n$taste\r\n$qty\r\n";

$file = fopen("$dir", "a");
fwrite($file,$new_data);
```

**when there is only one entry:** The above code is perfectly adding adding data in the txt file and replacing if it founds a match...

**when there is more than one entry:** It shows the above errors..

What am I doing wrong please help me....?

Or is there a better way to achieve what I want....?

Thanx in advance... :)

Comment: What would be your expected output ?

Comment: I want it to append the data into the text file, in case it finds that there is already a line present with the name of the fruit it is going to add, then replace it with current data @Rizier123

Comment: Please add your expected output with your example input file.

Comment: I've founded a way to get what I want, anyways Thanku :) @Rizier123